# iOS : how to programmatically auto layout a horizontal table view?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, tableview

I'm trying to write my own iOS menu and there I've got a horizontal UITableView as subview of my Custom UIView(my menu view). Now in layoutSubviews() I've got to lay out my UITableView (I'm using NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat for all other subviews) but the problem is that the tableViews 'height' ist actually it's 'width' 'cause it was turned sideways by 90 degrees with myTableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-CGFloat(M_PI_2)).

My layoutSubviews() :

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    let viewsDictionary = ["navigationTableView":navigationTableView, "settingsTableView":settingsTableView, "settingsTableViewContainerView":settingsTableViewContainerView, "settingsViewContainerView":settingsViewContainerView]
    let metricsDictionary = ["navigationTableViewHeight":100.0, "settingsTableViewContainerViewHeight":70.0, "settingsViewContainerViewHeight":0.0, "viewWidth":screen.bounds.width]

    navigationTableView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    settingsTableView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    settingsViewContainerView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    settingsTableViewContainerView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    // sizing constraints

    // navigationTableView
    let navigationTableView_constraint_H: Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[navigationTableView(viewWidth)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: metricsDictionary, views: viewsDictionary)
    let navigationTableView_constraint_V: Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[navigationTableView(>=navigationTableViewHeight)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: metricsDictionary, views: viewsDictionary)

    navigationTableView.addConstraints(navigationTableView_constraint_H)
    navigationTableView.addConstraints(navigationTableView_constraint_V)

    // settingsTableViewContainerView
    let settingsTableViewContainerView_constraint_H: Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[settingsTableViewContainerView(viewWidth)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: metricsDictionary, views: viewsDictionary)
    let settingsTableViewContainerView_constraint_V: Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[settingsTableViewContainerView(settingsTableViewContainerViewHeight)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: metricsDictionary, views: viewsDictionary)

    settingsTableViewContainerView.addConstraints(settingsTableViewContainerView_constraint_H)
    settingsTableViewContainerView.addConstraints(settingsTableViewContainerView_constraint_V)

    // settingsTableView
    /*let settingsTableView_constraint_H: Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[settingsTableView(settingsTableViewContainerViewHeight)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: metricsDictionary, views: viewsDictionary)
    let settingsTableView_constraint_V: Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[settingsTableView(viewWidth)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: metricsDictionary, views: viewsDictionary)

    settingsTableView.addConstraints(settingsTableView_constraint_H)
    settingsTableView.addConstraints(settingsTableView_constraint_V)*/

    // settingsViewContainerView
    let settingsViewContainerView_constraint_H: Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[settingsViewContainerView(viewWidth)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: metricsDictionary, views: viewsDictionary)
    let settingsViewContainerView_constraint_V: Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[settingsViewContainerView(settingsViewContainerViewHeight)]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: metricsDictionary, views: viewsDictionary)

    settingsViewContainerView.addConstraints(settingsViewContainerView_constraint_H)
    settingsViewContainerView.addConstraints(settingsViewContainerView_constraint_V)

    switch settingsTableViewPosition {
        case .Top:
            //Todo
        break
        case .Bottom:
            // positioning
            let settingsTableView_constraint_H: Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[settingsTableView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: metricsDictionary, views: viewsDictionary)
            let settingsTableView_constraint_V: Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[settingsTableView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: metricsDictionary, views: viewsDictionary)

            settingsTableViewContainerView.addConstraints(settingsTableView_constraint_H)
            settingsTableViewContainerView.addConstraints(settingsTableView_constraint_V)

            let view_constraint_H_navigationTableView: Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[navigationTableView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: metricsDictionary, views: viewsDictionary)
            let view_constraint_H_settingsTableView: Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[settingsTableViewContainerView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: metricsDictionary, views: viewsDictionary)
            let view_constraint_H_settingsViewContainerView: Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[settingsViewContainerView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: metricsDictionary, views: viewsDictionary)
            let view_constraint_V: Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[navigationTableView][settingsTableViewContainerView][settingsViewContainerView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: metricsDictionary, views: viewsDictionary)

            self.addConstraints(view_constraint_H_settingsTableView)
            self.addConstraints(view_constraint_H_navigationTableView)
            self.addConstraints(view_constraint_H_settingsViewContainerView)
            self.addConstraints(view_constraint_V)
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use UICollectionView instead of UITableView. 
This will fully solve you problem. 
From my experience you will get a lot of bugs in feature if you will "turn tableview sideways by 90 degrees".

I'm not sure but you can for your issue you can try to add tableview to container. 
Connect left,top,bottom,right constraints of tableview to container width .constant = 0. Then set up constraints for your container as usual. 
if it will not help setup tableview.height constraint to container.width constraint and tableview.width to container.height.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I've already tested what you suggest and the problem is that the UITableView's .Top is where the .Trailing should be after it's turned by 90 degrees. But I'll check out the UICollectionView and if that doesn't work for me I'll write my own UIHorizontalTableView inherited from UIScrollView

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to use custom container view for UITableView. 
Set up required constraints to custom container view. 
In layoutSubviews method of custom container view after calling it's super implementation setup width and height for uitableivew (tableview.height = container.width, tableview.width = container.height). 
I mean not to use constraints for uitableview.